# Disallow pages that ends with number only in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

Is it possible to tell Google not to crawl these pages

```
/blog/page/10
/blog/page/20
…
/blog/page/100
```

These are basically Ajax calls that bring blog posts data.

I created this in robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /blog/page/*
```

But now I have to another page that I want allow which is

```
/blog/page/start
```

Is there a way that I tell robots that only pages that end with a number 
e.g

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /blog/page/(:num)
```

I also got an error bellow when I tried to validate the robots.txt file:

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the original robots.txt specification, this would work (for all conforming bots, including Google’s):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /blog/pages/0
Disallow: /blog/pages/1
Disallow: /blog/pages/2
Disallow: /blog/pages/3
Disallow: /blog/pages/4
Disallow: /blog/pages/5
Disallow: /blog/pages/6
Disallow: /blog/pages/7
Disallow: /blog/pages/8
Disallow: /blog/pages/9
```

This blocks all URLs whose path **begins** with `/blog/pages/` followed by *any* number (`/blog/pages/9129831823`, `/blog/pages/9.html`, `/blog/pages/5/10/foo` etc.).
So you should not append the `*` character (it’s not a wildcard in the original robots.txt specification, and [not even needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22156788/1591669) in your case for bots that interpret it as wildcard).

Google supports some features for robots.txt which are not part of the original robots.txt specification, and therefore are not supported by (all) other bots, e.g., the `Allow` field. But as the above robots.txt would work, there is no need for using it.